# How to set/assign file to form file input in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, file, multipartform-data

I am using form in angular 7. I am getting image from one function and I need to set that image to the form input type with file.

This is how I did,

```
allData: FormGroup;
this.allData = this.fb.group({
  'image': ['']
});


testFunction(event){
    const file = event.target.files
    this.allData.get('image').setValue(file);
}
```

Here I am using testFunction for an input file type outside form and I can get the image from this function but when I assign file to the form input type file field it is not setting the value also no error throws while using setValue

Answer (score 0):

Use **FormData**

Try like this:

```
testFunction(event){
      const file = event.target.files
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrita Sharma for your answer. This looks like, sending image file to server. But my question is how to assign value to the form which has type file. The real scenario is, User can upload the image and they can crop their required size and sending cropped image to server with the same form field type file. So here i need to set  the cropped image to the form field from ts file